# Pattern matching find equal or less than using regular expression in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to find the data in a CSV file , comma FS file , which are (equal or less than) =< 30 using `awk` program. 
considering the following file as example

```
cat filename

    a,20
    b,39
    c,12
    d,34
    e,10
    f,23
    g,11
    h,65
```

I tried the following awk script but was not successful:

```
awk -F, '$2~/[0-9]=<30/' filename
awk -F, '$2~/\d =<30/' filename
awk -F, '$2~/*=<30/' filename
```

Comment: Can regular expression do that? How about simply `awk -F, '$2<=30' filename`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No regular expression needed for a simple integer comparison:

```
awk -F, '$2 <= 30 { print }' /path/to/filename
```

Comment: @ DopeGhoti. Tnx. Can u plz let me know why  (less than or equal) "=< " dose not work? do you have any idea how I can get this (less than or equal) in this somple integer comparison?

Comment: `<=` will also work in this case.

Comment: @ DopeGhoti. Tnx a lot again. Sorry for this question but can you plz let me know how to get the values between two values such as greater pr equal than 20 and less or equal to 30 ? I tried this >= 20 <= 30 but did not work !

Comment: `awk -F, '($2 <= 30) && ($2 >= 20) { print }' inputfile`

Comment: @ DopeGhoti. very much appreciated ur kind helps :)